# regular expression python `r'*(.|:|?|!)*'`

Tags: python, regex

I want to accept words that include these characters: `'.:?!'`
I tried this as pattern: `r'*(.|:|?|!)*'` but does not work.

How I implement this by using python `re`.

the code I'd like to run is like this:

```
import re
pattern = r'*(.|:|?|!)*'
word = '.Flask'
match = re.match(pattern, word)
if match:
    print('yes')
```

for example, I want to accept these words:`'.flask'`, `'flask.'`,`'!flask'`,`'flask!'`....

and even non ascii character. So I want to include those words as well:`.日本語`, `日本語.`

that's why I wanted to use `*` symbol.

Comment: You are keep on including conditions after posting the question. This renders the answers posted till now invalid.

Comment: sorry, I will be careful about this :(

Comment: Should these characters just be at the beginning or at the end of a line?

Comment: yes, one of these character have to be included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match words starting or ending with one of these characters, this regex should fit your needs:

```
pattern = r'[.:?!][^ ]*|[^ ]*[.:?!]'
```

Or even better with word boundary:

```
pattern = r'\b[.:?!][^ ]*\b|\b[^ ]*[.:?!]\b'
```

Explenation:

`[.:?!][^ ]*` matches words beginning with `[.:?!]` followed by all characters except whitespace.

`[^ ]*[.:?!]` matches all words beginning Wirth any character except whitespace ending with a `[.:?!]` character.

`\b` matches the word boundaries.

Comment: Thank you @miindlek and everyone who helps me !